# how to add dash/hyphen in input field after 2 digits angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, mask, directive

hey i want to add dashes when user enter date of birth manually.
like this
08-18-2019
but i cannot be able to do this

```
 public dateOfBirth: { year: number; month: number; day: number };
```

**html file**

```
 <input
          ngbDatepicker
          dobMask
          #d="ngbDatepicker"
          #dobF="ngModel"
          class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
          id="dob"
          [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth"
          placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"
          name="dp"
          [ngClass]="{
            invalid:
              (dobF.value === null || isString(dobF.value) || futureDate) && dobF.touched
          }"
          required
        />
```

i tried directive but result is something like this 
11---------3

**here is my directive code**

```
@Directive({
selector: '[dobMask]'
})
export class DobDirective {

@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

let trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');
if (trimmed.length > 8) {
  trimmed = trimmed.substr(0, 8);
}

let numbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < trimmed.length; i += 2) {
  numbers.push(trimmed.substr(i, 2));
}

input.value = numbers.join('-');

  }
}
```

this is what i am getting

[image]

my expected result is 
i.e 08-17-2019

can anyone help me how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified your directive a little bit and its working fine

```
import {Directive,HostListener} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
selector: '[dobMask]'
})
export class DobDirective {

@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

let trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '');

if (trimmed.length > 10) {
  trimmed = trimmed.substr(0, 10);
}


trimmed = trimmed.replace(/-/g,'');

 let numbers = [];
  numbers.push(trimmed.substr(0,2));
 if(trimmed.substr(2,2)!=="")
 numbers.push(trimmed.substr(2,2));
 if(trimmed.substr(4,4)!="")
 numbers.push(trimmed.substr(4,4));
input.value = numbers.join('-');

  }
}
```

1. First issue was  you were trimming with length 8 , it should be 10
   (including '-')

   2. Then for loop your were always increment 2 , that will not work out as we require 4 values in last item.
   3. Also you need to remove '-' before further you proceed with your logic.

check this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dnjfw

Comment: it worked partially but backspace not working 
like if i write 02-09-2019 then i remove it with backspace it will remove 2019 just
and will stuck on 02-09- @Midhun Murali

Comment: means 2 dashes are not removing

Comment: @UsmanSaleem just updated the answer , by adding a check before pushing to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use ngModelChange like so:

```
<input [ngModel]="dateOfBirth" (ngModelChange)="updateDateOfBirth($event)">
```

then in controller .ts file:

```
updateDateOfBirth(dob) {
  // some logic to insert hyphens if it is in a valid format
  // pseduocode:
  // IF dob matches required format THEN
  //   dob = dob with Hyphens inserted
  this.dateOfBirth = dob
}
```

the dob will update in the form control because of the binding `[ngModel]="dateOfBirth"`

Comment: what is dob? directive @danday74

Comment: dob is the current value in the input which ngOnChanges allows you to modify, which in turn will update the input value with the modifications